# Adding values from different fields within same row in ArcGIS field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

In my attribute table, I have over 200 fields and tens of thousands of rows or attributes. I am trying to sum the values in each field across each row. This seems like a basic function but when I search for this topic, I've only found instructions on summing entire fields. I could just select each individual field with a "+" in between in the field calculator but there has to be a simpler way than that.

Comment: The "simpler" way would be to write some ArcPy/Python code.  Perhaps using ArcPy's ListFields and Python's .join("+").

Comment: Databases and spreadsheets are very different animals. 10k rows is a *tiny* database table, and 200 columns is ungainly latge. Maybe you should be using a spreadsheet.

Comment: The issue I'm having with the spreadsheet is that Arc freezes whenever I try to join that file to my attribute table and populate the sum field using the field calculator. I figured there might be an easier way

Answer (score 2):

In the field calculator there isn't a simpler way as far as I know. I do not think that it is common to want to sum every field in a row without being selective of the fields to be summed. Python could be used in the field calculator to do this, but you would end up writing code that is better to run in a script.